# Libre Calc error on a float in decimal notation. Err. 519 (#value error)

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice

There is a problem with my libreoffice.
I doesn't calculate cells with decimal points, possibly seeing them as text.

[image]

I have checked my locale settings (you can see them in the picture above) that decimal separator is dot. Also I have unticked "Using regular expression" in Tools - Options

[image: http://i.imgur.com/mtgoYp1.png]

I have no idea how to fix that and force libre to understand this is float point number.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: with `LibreOffice 3.5.4.2` on GNU/Linux it works fine, i.e. `0.6*10` gives `6`. But if I write `0,6` in A1, then I get `#VALUE!` of course. So the only guess we can do, it's that the cell is not seen as containing a number. You say you are sure dot is decimal separator, but have you tried 1) writing `0,6` instead, 2) taking a loot at the format of the cell?

Comment: 1) yes
2) no. your suggestion directed me to check locale settings.
This helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what it was. The error was weird and it was about cell formatting.
Turns out, that locale was set, as first screenshot in question states, to "Default - English (USA)".
And that exactly caused a problem. Unfortunately, I can't explain why.
[image]
Setting cell formatting locale to "English (USA)" fixed the cell. And setting "English (USA)" in settings had fixed problem to the whole file altogether.